# vue 3 build + webpack causes JavaScript heap out of memory

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, vue-loader

In my local build environment, there are some directories at the base directory where my webpack config is.  These directories contain quite a few files (they are other applications that are part of our debugging environment).

```
node_modules/
src/
src/components
dir1/
dir2/
webpack.config.js
packages.json
```

I am using `exclude` to exclude the `dir1` and `dir2`, but this doesn't help.  The build does complete if I remove these directories completely.  So it seems that whatever is consuming all the memory is running before the 'exclude' rule is applied.  Note, I am *not* interested in increasing the memory limit of node, I don't think that is real problem.  I'd prefer not to have to do some magic with logical file links.

Any ideas?

I suspect the problem is actually with vue-loader plugin, but I can't be sure because i don't see any error other then the dump, even when I use 'verbose' flag in webpack.

Below is my webpack config (I am using grunt to initiate the build).  `exclude` and `include` contain absolute path to the files (include) or the directories to exclude (exclude).  I also tried exclude with regular expressions.

I also added the relevant parts of my package.json

```js
rules: [
        {
          test: /(\.ts$|\.js$)/,
          exclude,
          include,
          use: [
            {
              loader: 'ts-loader',
            },
          ],
        }, {
          exclude,
          test: /\.vue$/,
          use: 'vue-loader'
        }, {
          exclude,
          test: /\.css$/,
          use: ['vue-style-loader', 'css-loader']
        }

      ],
```

```json
"devDependencies": {
    "css-loader": "^6.5.1",
    "@vue/compiler-sfc": "^3.2.29",
    "grunt": "^1.4.1",
    "grunt-bump": "^0.8.0",
    "grunt-cli": "^1.4.3",
    "grunt-webpack": "^5.0.0",
    "jsdom": "^19.0.0",
    "npm": "^8.3.2",
    "ts-loader": "^9.2.6",
    "typescript": "^4.5.4",
    "vue": "^3.2.29",
    "vue-loader": "^17.0.0",
    "vue-style-loader": "^4.1.3",
    "webpack": "^5.67.0"
  }
```

Error:

```
<--- Last few GCs --->

[30416:000002A93B75B4D0]    82287 ms: Mark-sweep (reduce) 4094.2 (4101.3) -> 4093.9 (4103.1) MB, 2689.3 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.091, current mu = 0.004) allocation failure scavenge might not succeed
[30416:000002A93B75B4D0]    86891 ms: Mark-sweep (reduce) 4094.9 (4105.1) -> 4094.6 (4105.6) MB, 4588.9 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.037, current mu = 0.003) allocation failure scavenge might not succeed


<--- JS stacktrace --->

FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
1: 00007FF7BD3E046F napi_wrap+109311
```

Answer (score 0):

Either you have too many files or you have few files that are too large. The only thing you can do is try increasing the memory quota using the `node` flag `--max-old-space-size`.

Before running the Webpack, set the memory options using environment variables:

```
// 8GB of memory
NODE_OPTIONS=--max_old_space_size=8192
```

And, then run your Webpack command. Alternately, you can also use:

```
node --max-old-space-size=8192 ./node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js
```

Comment: what is 'too many, too big' ?  These files aren't a part of my project, and I want to exclude them altogether.  I don't want to just keep increasing my heap size.  And I think I figured it out, it was the tsconfig.

Answer (score 0):

The problem turned out to be my tsconfig.json.   There is also an exclude rule in that file.  Next time I opened VS Code, it reminded me to check that file for excludes.  It knew!  Once I added the large directory to the tsconfig exclude rule, the problem went away.

So I guess this doesn't have to do with vue or vue-loader  or even webpack specifically (unless one of those also uses the tsconfig).  But I didn't think of this, because mine is a pure .js app and prior to vue, there was no need for tsconfig.

I also realize I didn't include that config in my question:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6" /* Specify ECMAScript target version: 'ES3' (default), 'ES5', 'ES2015', 'ES2016', 'ES2017', 'ES2018', 'ES2019', 'ES2020', or 'ESNEXT'. */,
    "module": "esnext" /* Specify module code generation: 'none', 'commonjs', 'amd', 'system', 'umd', 'es2015', 'es2020', or 'ESNext'. */,
    "allowJs": true /* Allow javascript files to be compiled. */,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "./build",
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "declaration": false,
    "strict": true /* Enable all strict type-checking options. */,
    "esModuleInterop": true /* Enables emit interoperability between CommonJS and ES Modules via creation of namespace objects for all imports. Implies 'allowSyntheticDefaultImports'. */,
    "skipLibCheck": true /* Skip type checking of declaration files. */,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true /* Disallow inconsistently-cased references to the same file. */,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "lib": ["dom", "es2017"],
    "removeComments": false
  },
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "ise", "bin", "obj", "kite"]
}
```